# Большая таблица angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Есть json файл ~20000 записей. если я делаю

```
$http.get('file.json')
    .success(function (result) {
        for (var i = 0; i < result.aaData.length; i++) { 
            $scope.row.push(result.aaData[i]);
        }
    });
```

браузер просто виснет. Но если я буду писать

```
for (var j = 0; j < 200000; j++) {
    $scope.row.push(generateRandomItem(j));
}
```

Прогружает даже такое дикое кол-во записей но стоит мне написать

```
$http.get('file.json')
    .success(function (result) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 200000; j++) {
            $scope.row.push(generateRandomItem(j));
        }
    });
```

Как снова браузер зависает намертво. Какие есть идеи как решить данную проблему и как вообще на angularjs выводить большую таблицу?

Comment: Очень похоже что может быть баг в angular. Я бы уменьшил количество с 200000 до 200 и запустил profiler (dev tools-> profiles).

Comment: До 20000 грузит нормально. Больше виснет браузер....

Comment: Количество не важно. Запустите что бы работало и смотрите в профайлере, что жрет ресурсы

Comment: Что такое `$scope.row` и почему тут `push`, а не присваивание?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Короче не знаю с чем связано но если использывать [смарт теибл](https://lorenzofox3.github.io/)

и писать так

```
        $scope.itemsByPage = 15;

    $scope.rowCollection = [];
$scope.displayed=[];

    $http.get('get.json')
            .success(function (result) {
                var rowCollection = result.aaData;
        $scope.rowCollection = rowCollection;

            });
```

после чего во вьюшки

```
<table st-table="displayed" st-safe-src="rowCollection" class="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th st-sort="firstName">first name</th>
                                <th st-sort="lastName">last name</th>
                                <th st-sort="birthDate">birth date</th>
                                <th st-sort="balance">balance</th>
                                <th>email</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    <input st-search="firstName" placeholder="search for firstname" class="input-sm form-control" type="search"/>
                                </th>
                                <th colspan="4">
                                    <input st-search placeholder="global search" class="input-sm form-control" type="search"/>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="row in displayed">
                                <td>{{row.name | uppercase}}</td>
                                <td>{{row.lastName}}</td>
                                <td>{{row.birthDate| date}}</td>
                                <td>{{row.balance| currency}}</td>
                                <td><a ng-href="mailto:{{row.email}}">email</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="5" class="text-center">
                                    <div st-pagination="" st-items-by-page="itemsByPage" st-displayed-pages="7"></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
```

то загрузка 8362 элиментов занимает не больше 3 секунд и браузер не подвисает. Если же делать в виде теста

```
    for (var j = 0; j < 200000; j++) {
    $scope.rowCollection.push(generateRandomItem(j));
}
```

то загружается буквально моментально.

Весь подвох был в том что я писал st-table="rowCollection" и потом ng-repeat="row in rowCollection" а надо было так **st-table="displayed" st-safe-src="rowCollection"** и потом уже ng-repeat="row in **displayed**"
В чём подвох пока не читал но если кто то поиснит буду благодарен

Comment: stSafeSrc attribute
If you are bringing in data asynchronously (from a remote database, restful endpoint, ajax call, etc) you must use the stSafeSrc attribute. You must use a seperate collection for both the base and safe collections or you may end up with an infinite loop.

Это из документации.

Answer (score 0):

Просто закинь всю таблицу `result.aaData` в `$scope.row` 
Тут суть в том, что на каждую попытку изменить  массив, браузер вызывает ререндер (20000 рендеров за время загрузки). Твоя задача загрузить это за раз, либо не сразу в скоуп, а через просежуточную переменную

Comment: то есть ты предлагаешь 
                $http.get('file.json')
                    .success(function (result) {
                     $scope.row.result.aaData
               });

Comment: а потом 
ng-repeat="$scope.row.result.aaData in row"?

Comment: Э? Какой рендерер и с чего бы ему его вызывать?

Comment: Я предлагаю $http.get('file.json') .success(function (result) { $scope.row = result.aaData; });

Comment: ограничил выгрузку в 9000 строк подвисание происходят но не значительные. а если делаю через 
"$resource('get_clients.php').query().$promise.then(function(clients) {

      vm.clients = clients;
    });"

То постояно получаю что скрипт не отвечает а по профайлу получаю красным вот такое "Малая GC длительность 13,44мс причина: Nursery Object to Active Тип: Nursery Collection"